# Integrate out the binary indicator variable in a two-sample ANOVA

Tags: distributions, density-function, marginal-distribution, integral

I have two sets of data, A and B, that have unequal sizes, and I want to compare their means. The standard approach would be to do a t-test. Getting a little more sophisticated, we can think of that t-test as a two-sample ANOVA and, therefore, a regression with a binary variable as the predictor.

```
X |  Y
__|_____
0 | 0
0 | 1
1 | 10
1 | 11
1 | 12
1 | 13
```

$X$ is the binary predictor, so $Y\vert X=0$ is group A, and $Y\vert X=1$ is group B.

There is now a bivariate distribution. I want to find the marginal distribution of $Y$.

The way that I am approaching this is to sum the joint density $(X,Y)\sim g(x,y)$ over the $X$ values of $0$ and $1$:

$$f_Y(y) = \sum_{x=0}^1 g(x,y) = g(0,y) + g(1,y)$$

This integrates out $X$.

However, doesn't this integrate to 2 instead of 1, since $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(0,y)dy = 1 = \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(1,y)dy\text{?}$ Is this just an issue of "Oh, yeah, divide at the end by the integral to make it integrate to 1"?